# Search for the object with a known value in JSON

Tags: linux, json

Let's say I have a JSON like the following but with much more data and much more nesting

```json
{
  "dont_want_1": {
    "a": 1
  },
  "dont_want_2": {
    "b": 2
  },
  "find_me_1": [
    { "similarly_interesting_1": "this is a string" },
    { "similarly_interesting_2": "this is a string" },
    { "find_me_2": "look for me" },
    { "similarly_interesting_3": "this is a string" },
    { "similarly_interesting_4": "this is a string" }
  ],
  "dont_want_3": {
    "c": 3
  },
  "dont_want_4": {
    "d": 4
  }
}
```

I want to eventually get a bunch of similar objects with `jq` (the final results will be `similarly_interesting_1` and its sibling objects). I know that I want to look for an object whose value is `look for me`. Running something like `find_obj data.json "look for me"` should return something like `find_me_1[2].find_me_2` in this case. From that output, I can run `cat data.json | jq '.find_me_1[]'` to get all those objects.

```sh
$ cat data.json | jq '.find_me_1[]'
{
  "similarly_interesting_1": "this is a string"
}
{
  "similarly_interesting_2": "this is a string"
}
{
  "find_me_2": "this a a string abc please look for me"
}
{
  "similarly_interesting_3": "this is a string"
}
{
  "similarly_interesting_4": "this is a string"
}
```

Is there a way to do such `find_str` with a standard tool like `jq`?